# how to use usecontext for fetch api

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, react-context

I'm using react hooks + context to manage state. However, I've run into this issue, where React.useContext() returns undefined even though I'm passing in my context object (or so I think, anyway). Am I missing something really obvious? What's happening?

I have been trying to fetch data from localhost server using usecontext but it is showing undefined. the data is fetched correctly if i fetch it in app.js.

StateContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const StateContext = (props) => {
  
  const StateContext = createContext();


  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getData = async () => {
    let url = "http://localhost:4000/products";
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    setData(parsedData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={data}>
      {props.children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default StateContext;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Products from './Products/Products';

function App(props) { 
  return (
    <div>
      <Products />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Product.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import StateContext from '../Context/StateContext'

const Products = () => {
  const context = useContext(StateContext)
  const data = context
  return (
    <div>
      Products
      {console.log(data)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Products
```

Comment: Move `const StateContext = createContext();` outside of the `StateContext` component and rename the `StateContext` component to something other, like `StateProvider`. And export it at the end: `export default StateProvider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `context`, you need to wrap your app code in the `Provider` in order to **provide** the context to all components.

> Context.Provider component available on the context instance is used
> to provide the context to its child components, no matter how deep
> they are.
> ... what's important here is that all the components that'd like later
> to consume the context have to be wrapped inside the provider
> component.

https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-context-and-usecontext/

So you should wrap your App.js code in the `StateContext` component which returns the `Provider` like this:

```
function App(props) { 
  return (
    <StateContext>
      <div>
        <Products />
      </div>
    </StateContext>
  );
}
```

**Edit:**
You also forgot to **export** the `StateContext` variable itself.

**Your code:**

```
  const StateContext = createContext();
```

**Should be:**

```
export const StateContext = createContext();
```

And when you import the context variable only, you need to import it like this (in Product.js):

```
import {StateContext} from '../Context/StateContext'
```

But when you import the **entire** component that returns the Provider (in App.js)
You need to import it like this (Because this is the **default** export in the `StateContext.js`) :

```
import StateContext from './Context/StateContext'
```

I would advise you to change the component name to *"StateContextProvider"* or something so it won't confuse you.

Comment: It is still showing undefined.

Comment: You forgot to export the Context variable itself, and also you need to import it between : ```{ }``` . See the edit in my answer.